# How to Fix The Hover Effect

Tags: html, css

I'm building a navigation bar and the code if fine in the desktop mode. 
When I'm using media queries for mobile, the hover effects are the same in the media query as in the desktop version. I don't know what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it.

```
background: #232323;
height: 66px;
color: #ffff;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px green;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;


}


header .logo {

float: left;
height: inherit;
margin-left: 3em;
margin-bottom: 3em;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;

}


header .logo-text {

margin: 8px;

}


header .logo-text span {

color: #cfe333;
font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;


}

header ul {

float: right;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style: none;

}




header ul li {

float: left;
position: relative


}

header ul li ul {
position: absolute;
top: 66px;
right: 0px;
width: 180px;
display: none;


}

header ul li ul li {

width: 100%;
background: #cfe333;

}


header ul li ul:hover {


background: #0000;
width: 180px;
height: 66px;

}



header ul li ul li a {

padding: 10px;
color: #fffff;
height: 66px;

}


header ul li  {

display: block;
padding: 21px;
font-size: 1.1em;



}

header ul li:hover {

background: #010101;
color: #cfe333;


}


header ul li a:hover {
color: #cfe333;
transition: 0.5s;

}

header .menu-toggle {

display: none;



}

header ul li a {

text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
font-size: 1.2em;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;


}

.fas fa-bars menu-toggle {

color: white;


}


/* Media Queries */

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {

header ul {

width: 100%;
background: #232323;
font-size: .8em;
margin-top: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 68px;


}

header ul li {

width: 100%;


}

header ul li ul {
position: static;
display: block;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
margin-top: 30px;

}

header ul li ul li a {

padding: 10px;
color: #fffff;
height: 66px;
width: 100%;



}

header ul li ul li a:hover {


width: 100%;


}

}


</style>

</head>

<body>

<header>
<div class="logo">
<h1 class="logo-text"><span>IM</span> Learning Project</h1>

<link rel="stylysheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity=""
crossorigin="anonymous">


</div>

<i class="fas fa-bars menu-toggle"></i>
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#rewards"><i class="far fa-star"></i> Rewards</a></li>
<li><a href="#connect"><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i> Connect</a></li>
<li><a href="#watch"><i class="fas fa-video"></i> Watch</a></li>

<li>
<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Sign Up <i class="fas fa-chevron-down" style="font-size: .8em;"></i></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="logout">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>

</header>
```

What I'm trying to do with this code is have the list items stay the full width on hover also, for the media query.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Hover on mobile is tap and holding the element (I think) since there's no actual cursor to move. Were you doing that originally?

Comment: No, I was just building it out on the laptop. It's glitchy and doesn't go full width when I hover on it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by putting a media query on this:

````
header ul li ul:hover {


background: #0000;
width: 180px;
height: 66px;

}

}```
````